# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Windows' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, iis, operating-system, windows-services, buildmaster

I have an application which I am deploying on my home Windows server through BuildMaster and lately an error occurs while deploying. Mostly the error is when I restart the server and after several minutes the error seems to disappear while deploying again. The problem occurs while services are stopping.

```
Stopping service CustomerHost... 
An unhandled exception occurred while executing this action: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Windows' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
File name: 'Windows'    
at Inedo.BuildMaster.Extensibility.Agents.LegacyTcp.TcpAgentClient.RunJob(ITcpAgentCommand command, Action`2 log)    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at Inedo.TaskExtensions.Result[TResult](Task`1 task)   
 at Inedo.Agents.RemoteJobExecuter.ExecuteJob(IRemoteJobExecuter jobExecuter, RemoteJob job)    
at Inedo.BuildMaster.Extensibility.Actions.RemoteActionBase.ExecuteRemoteCommand(String name, String[] args)    
at Inedo.BuildMaster.Extensibility.Actions.ActionBase.ExecuteInternal(IActionExecutionContext context, ExtensionConfigurerBase extensionConfigurer, Boolean resumeNextOnError, Boolean logErrorsAsWarnings)

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under executable  C:\BuildMasterAgent\Agent\bmtcpagent.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 


=== Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Windows  (Partial) 
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly: 
WRN: Assembly Name: Windows | Domain ID: 1 
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided. 
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly. 
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly, 
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token. 
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue. 
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/BuildMasterAgent/Agent/ 
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : InedoLib, Version=521.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=********.
=== 
LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\BuildMasterAgent\Agent\bmtcpagent.exe.Config 
LOG: Using host configuration file:  
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. 
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). 
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/BuildMasterAgent/Agent/Windows.DLL. 
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/BuildMasterAgent/Agent/Windows/Windows.DLL. 
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/BuildMasterAgent/Agent/Windows.EXE. 
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/BuildMasterAgent/Agent/Windows/Windows.EXE. Action Group 0: All Deployables 
Action 0:  Custom Variables: (none) 
Initializing server 2... 
Server ShoppingServer (ID: 2) initialized.
```

Comment: Please make sure the application pool identity has permissions on the DLL file and its dependencies.

Comment: Hello @samwu thank you for the reply. I have added full permissions on the DLL file and its dependencies, no luck, issue is still appearing. Here's the process: I am starting the deploy, the first task is done, and when the Stop Services process comes up, it's initializing stop process for the first service and it fails giving the exception. I don't know if it's a permission problem or different version of DLL. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try this solution: Open IIS Manager -> Select Application Pools -> go to advanced settings -> Change the flag of Enable 32-bit application false to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dependentAssembly in web.config file.